# Wifi and settings system are missing

Tags: networking, wireless, system-settings, gnome-control-center

I installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS this week. So at first, I had a problem with the wifi connection. It really was not stable; wifi was disconnected every 5 minutes. So I googled about it and tried this command:

```
sudo apt install wicd-gtk
```

Then, I somehow uninstalled `network-manager`

```
sudo apt remove network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

and I rebooted.

Unfortunately, that made it even worse as the settings menu disappeared.
So basically I can't connect to wifi and I can't open the settings menu.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt install-gnome-control-center
```

and also many more commands. I'm kind of new to Ubuntu.

Comment: The "settings-menu" was in Network Manager, you removed it.

Comment: It would be easier to re-install. And don't try to do stupid things like removing NM. It won't make your Wi-Fi better.

Comment: sudo apt install gnome-control-center. This fixed the issue on my side

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use wicd as the problem is probably with your network.

If you need to get to the network, run the following command:

```
wicd-gtk
```

If you get a permission error, run this instead:

```
sudo -i wicd-gtk
```

Once you have a network connection, reinstall network-manager:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Now, start network-manager and uninstall wicd-gtk

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
sudo apt remove wicd-gtk
```

Finally, set your IP to a static IP address to prevent DHCP problems that cause your network to drop.

After you are connected to the network, click on the network settings and select "Connection information". Click on the network settings again and then "Edit connections" and select your network.

Select "IPv4 Settings" and under "Method:" select "Manual".

**Now, you must enter the next three one-by-one and use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key in between. If you mess up, click <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and start over.**

- For "Address" enter your "IP Address" listed on your connection information window and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
- For "Netmask" enter "255.255.255.0" and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
- For "Gateway" enter your "Default Route" listed on your connection information window and then press
  <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Now, click on "DNS servers" and here you can either enter your "Default Route" or you can enter something like "8.8.8.8" to use google servers.

Then click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

Finally, run the following command to restart NetworkManager:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

---

Also, to prevent your network from dropping, you should make sure your wifi router is not using the same channel as your neighbors. Additionally, you should set the static IP address for your Ubuntu device in your router settings as well.

If you are still having trouble, please ask a new question addressing the wireless dropping issue and [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115) to provide the relevant information.